# CSS Transform and jQuery position() not working together

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm building a tool letting a user drag and lay out elements that can be saved and reloaded at a later date. I'm using jQuery's `position()` function to save the positions relative to the container which are used to *re-plot* the elements when they are loaded.

I've just added a rotate function with the transform origin set to the mid-point of each element but when I save and re-plot the elements aren't exactly where I put them, they're slightly offset.

Here are some values I recorded when saving and then when *re-plotting:*

```
Rotation | Position Saving | Position Re-plotted

0deg     | 250, 150        | 250, 150

45deg    | 239, 264        | 229, 254

90deg    | 250, 400        | 250, 400

135deg   | 239, 514        | 229, 504
```

I can't seem to figure out why it would shift. All of these positions are taken after rotation so it's not that causing the offset as far as I can tell.